# Is it just fine to install windows 8.1 on old version of motherboards?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, compatibility

Motherboards today says they are **window 8 ready** 
Im curious if i installed window 8.1 on a motherboard that doesn't mention windows 8 is just fine..

Sorry, im away from home and cannot pull the mobo model

Answer (score 4):

You'll likely find that the "Windows 8 Ready" label is a marketing tool designed to push sales. The [motherboard in my desktop PC](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2743#ov) at home was "Windows Vista Certified", yet it is running Windows 7 and has run Windows 8 with no issue. However, it is probably a good idea to check your motherboard manufacturers website for Windows 8 compatible drivers for things like Networking and On-board VGA or Audio. As long as the motherboard isn't too ancient, many manufacturers will continue to release updated drivers/firmware for previous generation models.

As long as you meet the [minimum system requirements](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-NZ/windows-8/system-requirements) (and they aren't very demanding), you're not likely to run into any issues. But if you need that extra assurance, you can always run the [Windows Upgrade Assistant](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-nz/windows-8/upgrade-assistant-download-online-faq) to get your PC checked out first.

**BONUS ROUND!**

Here are [some features](http://event.asus.com/mb/windows_8/) that ASUS have included in one of their recent motherboards which was the first Windows 8 certified motherboard available.

Comment: The only major Windows 8 specific a motherboard might have is `Secure Boot`.  Windows 8 of course will install on a MBR partition which means its either running in legacy mode or actually has a BIOS.